# Multiplying a set equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by an invertible matrix preserves equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question from my Linear Algebra course, I'm not sure how to prove it specifically because I know that multiplying by an invertible matrix produces a unique result but I'm not sure how to show that two unique results can't be scalar multiples of eachother or be a linear combination of another result (thus changing linear independence and possibly equality to R^n)

Assume that $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_k\}=\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $A$ is an invertible matrix.  Prove that
$\operatorname{span} \{A\vec{v}_1,\ldots,A\vec{v}_k\}=\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $A$ is invertible, than any vector $w\in\Bbb{R}^n$ can be written uniquely as $Ax$ for some $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$ ($A$ is one-to-one and onto).  Expand $x$ as $x=\sum_{j\leq k}\alpha_j v_j$, then $w=Ax=\sum_{j\leq k}\alpha_j Av_j$.  Uniqueness is not necessary to show span - we only require an expansion exists for each $w\in\Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, since $A$ is invertible, there's $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $Ax=y$.

Moreover, there are reals $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ s.t.
$$x=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i,$$
hence

$$y=Ax=\sum_i\alpha_i Av_i.$$
We conclude that 
$$\mathbb{R}^n=\mathrm{span}\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_k\}.$$

Another way to find the result: the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ so it contains a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and since $A$ is invertible, it tranforms a basis to a basis, hence the set $\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_k\} $ contains also a basis so it spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I don't understand how you're jumping to "we conclude that" in the first part. We've multiplied x by A, and there's a unique y, but how we know that each unique y isn't just a scalar multiple of another y?

Comment: @snario I proved that every $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear combination of $Av_i$ and this is sufficient to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mbox{span}\{A\vec{v_j}\}=A(\mbox{span}\{\vec{v_j}\})=A(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n
$$

Comment: Simple, I like it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to multiply a matrix by $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @snario It makes a lot of sense. If you prefer, it is $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Some people use this shortcut. Sorry if you don't like it. I'll edit.